# I can't get the array storaged in a getter using vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

i cant access to a getter in vuex. I wanna see the array that is in my state but i got a function. This is my vuex main

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import quoter from "@/modules/quoter/store"

const store = createStore({
  modules:{
    quoter
  }
});

export default store
```

my module index

```
import state from './state'
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as getters from './getters'
import * as mutations from './mutations'


const quoterModule = {
    namespaced: true,
    actions,
    getters,
    mutations,
    state
}


export default quoterModule
```

my getter

```
export const getterBrands = ( state ) =>  {
    return state.brands
}
```

my composable

```
import { computed,  } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

const useQuoter = () => {
    const store = useStore()
    computed(store.getters['quoter/getterBrands'])
    return {
        getBrands: () => store.dispatch('quoter/getBrands'),
        brands: () => computed(store.getters['quoter/getterBrands'])
    }
}

export default useQuoter
```

and i called it in my component as this

```
const { getBrands, brands} = useQuoter()
    onMounted (() => {
      getBrands()
      console.log(brands);
    })
```

but I got this function in my console log

[image]

and if i run the function i got this

[image]
please help me :C

i cant access to a getter in vuex. I wanna see the array that is in my state but i got a function and if i run that function i cant get the value

Comment: It's a function because you made it a function. It's a mistake to use `computed(store.getters...`, check how composition api is used. Should be `brands: computed(() => ...)`

Comment: thanks for answering me, it wasn't the whole solution but it helps me a lot. I have solved it. Nice day